# How can I have different responses for different prefixes of a webserver?

Tags: c#

I am working on teaching myself C#, and am using a localhost webserver to display some data. How can I have different prefixes (ex: /home, /stats) display different webpages?

Start Server:

```
        private static Thread responseThread;


        public static void StartServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
            HttpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/");
            HttpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/home/");
            HttpListener.Start(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
            responseThread = new Thread(ResponseThread);
            responseThread.Start(); 
            
        }
```

Response

```
private static HttpListenerContext context;
        private static void ResponseThread()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                const string path = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\EchoStatsLogger\\savedData.json";
                var toWrite = Convert.ToString(File.ReadAllText(path));
                // Now, you'll find the request URL in context.Request.Url
                var responseArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toWrite); // get the bytes to response
                context = HttpListener.GetContext(); // get a context
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(responseArray, 0,
                    responseArray.Length); // write bytes to the output stream
                context.Response.KeepAlive = false; // set the KeepAlive bool to false
                context.Response.Close(); // close the connection
                Console.WriteLine("Server data has been requested.");
                ReloadPage();
            }
            // ReSharper disable once FunctionNeverReturns
        }
```

Page Reloader (runs every time page refreshes, but doesn't exactly work, requires 2 refreshes to update data)

```
        private static void ReloadPage()
        {
            var contextNew = HttpListener.GetContext();
            contextNew.Response.Redirect("http://localhost:5000/");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Look at `context.Request.Url`.

Comment: *I am working on teaching myself C#* - you're starting pretty low level then! If you want to use the wheel that microsoft already invented for this, make an ASP.NET Core Web App or ASP.NET Core Web API project in your visual studio

Comment: Your ResponseThread is going to be constantly reloading that file; that seems like a Bad Idea, especially with the `while (true)` in there with no `break`. As @CaiusJard mentions, ASP.NET does most of this already, and you are rarely going to need to write your own static web server from scratch.

Comment: Like @CaiusJard this is not usually how you would create a web service. Look at the .NET 6 minimal web API or a traditional .NET ASP application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: (Good point from Keiran there; if you can't see the project templates I mentioned, you might not have the web workflows installed' you'll need to launch the VS installer and add the relevant web development features)

Comment: @Heretic [`HttpListener.GetContext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.getcontext?view=net-6.0) "waits for an incoming request and returns when one is received".

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I'll look into ASP.Net. Would you recommend using Visual Studio over something else, like Rider? Or does it not make a difference as long as I have the right features installed.